# writing security constraints for dynamic data in aspect

Tags: c#, spring, security, aspect

I have a simple app with n tier architecture using hibernate.

I want to secure my dal using spring aspect.
For example. A certain sales guy can see only customers from UK and US.
So I need to go to his session just before GetCustomers() , get the allowed countries and add it somehow to  to the query of GetCustomers.

What is the way to do that. Is it possible? Is it right?
Tx